NavigationStack out of sync with custom back button
Using a NavigationStack and manipulating the NavigationPath “too fast” compared to the animation of the screen can lead visual artifacts and invalid state.
For example, let's create simple stack and create a custom back button.
struct StepView: View {
    let value: Int
    let action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value)")
            Button("Next", action: action)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigationPath: [Int] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !self.navigationPath.isEmpty {
                Button("Back customg") {
                    self.navigationPath.removeLast()
                }
            }
            Divider()

            NavigationStack(path: self.$navigationPath) {
                Text("Root")
                Button("Next") {
                    self.navigationPath.append(1)
                }

                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { integer in
                    StepView(value: integer) {
                        self.navigationPath.append(integer + 1)
                    }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Smashing the custom back button will display some blank screens and lead to the application crashing.
Am I missing something missing with the usage of the API?

NavigationStack just isn't designed with this in mind. Navigation isn't supposed to be controlled by views outside the NavigationStack, I don't think.

I think this is just the general problem with SwiftUI's state-driven design. UI interactions are actually events and your multiple back events are tripping up the state. You could try changing with path with animations disabled.
